# Are recasts a hotter research topic than prompts in SLA? If so, why?

Tags: second-lang-acquisition, applied-linguistics

It seems that much research concerning corrective feedback in SLA is assuming a recasts-prompts dichotomy, and researchers are willing to further examine recasts in terms of implicitness/explicitness. But research concerning sub-categories of prompts (repetition, elicitation, clarification request, metalinguistic clue) is much less (or maybe it's because I haven't read enough; if that's the case, will you please provide some research concerning these four finer types of corrective feedback?). Is my impression correct? If so, what may be the possible reasons for such research preference?

Comment: This is also a good question for [languagelearning.se] but this does not make it off-topic here.

Comment: A comprehensive review of this: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/161451939.pdf